# Can't start react native app no emulator found

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

i'm on windows10 and setting up the environment as far as the react native docs goes.

I try to run `npx react-native run-android` and got the famous error  `error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of emulator -list-avds`

But my emulator is opened and I can see the device on `adb devices -l`, android sdk is as reccommended (android 10q and tools version 29.0.0.2)

I even try to connect my phone on (again, seen  in `adb devices -l`) but nothing works so far.

I'm pretty sure all of environment path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. What I do is is run this command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then in your emulator find your app and open it.

Comment: that doesn't help ;_;